# Python3 - modifying superclass method with multiple conditionals

Tags: python-3.x, oop

Please take a look at the sample code below:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.lst = []

    def method(self, b):
        if self.a < b.length:
            return False
        else:
            self.lst.append(b)
            return True

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, x, a):
        super().__init__(self, a)
        self.x = x

    def method(self, b):
        if self.a < b.length:
            return False
        **elif self.x < b.length:
            return False**
        else:
            self.lst.append(b)
            **self.x -= b.length**
            return True
```

I am trying to modify the method from the Parent class to add on additional conditions to the method under the Child class.

I understand that for the first bolded expression, I could just use the code like this:

```
def method(self, b):
    if self.x < b.length:
        return False
    else:
        super().method(b)
```

But I dont know how to integrate the second bolded expression into the inherited method. Anyone knows of a way to reduce the repetitive code?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I don't think you can do that.